# Is there distinction between the commands understood by the MySQL client and understood by the MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

When using MySQL in command line (such as Bash),

- is there a similar distinction between PostgreSQL server and client psql? If yes, what are the MySQL client and MySQL server when I run `mysql` in a OS shell? I never see in MySQL document a distinction between MySQL client/shell and MySQL server.
- is there distinction between the commands understood by the MySQL client and understood by the MySQL server?
  For comparison, in Postgresql, psql has its own commands usually started with `\`, such as `\l`, while postgresql server only understands SQL commands and doesn't understand psql commands.
  In MySQL official document, I don't find it mentions whether a command is only understood by the MySQL client or by the MySQL server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line client `mysql` also has commands that are interpreted by the client program rather than sent to the server.

Like for `psql`, these commands start with a backslash.

You can find a list in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: Thanks Is it correct that all commands not started with a backslash are understood by MySQL server?

Comment: Not necessarily understood by, but sent to.